# from curl -d to HTTParty get response

Tags: ruby, http, curl

I need to convert from

```
curl -d "params" "url"
```

To HTTParty.get request

so here's my curl:

```
curl -d 'email=myadmin@mycompany.com.au&password=mypassword' 'http://localhost:8080/locomotive/api/tokens.json'
```

So what is equivalent in `httparty`?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
HTTParty.post("#{my_host}/locomotive/api/tokens.json", body: {:email => "myadmin@mycompany.com.au", :password => "mypassword"})
```

Comment: anyone wants to refactor?

Comment: Can you do: HTTParty.post("#{my_host}/locomotive/api/tokens.json", body: {email: "myadmin@mycompany.com.au", password: "mypassword"})